# Create List dynamically in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, variables, qlist

I have a struct and a QList of struct. Based on a count I want to create multiple QList.

For eg:

```
struct Data
{
    QString id;
    QString name;
};

QList<Data> lst;
```

Suppose if I have 3 values in lst, I want to create 3 QList.

```
for(int i=0;i<=lst.count();i++)
{
     //Declare new list here for each.
     //Result 3 lists : QList<Data> lst1,QList<Data> lst2,QList<Data> lst3
}
```

Can someone please tell me if this is possible in Qt? Is there a way out?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, what would you like to do with these lists further?

Comment: One solution: make a list of lists...

Comment: @demonplus : i would like to populate these list with another set of data based on varous conditions. lst1 would have all the data where id=1(id is not unique here).

Comment: @king_nak : How can a list of lists help in declaration? Could you pls elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare a variing number of variables. Instead, you make lists (or other containers).

From your comment (*lst1 would have all the data where id=1*), I would suggest to use a `QMap<int, QList<Data>>`. E.g.

```
QMap<int, QList<Data>> lstN;
QList<Data> lst;
for(int i=0;i<lst.count();i++)
{
    lstN[lst[i].id] << lst[i];
}
```

This gives you a mapping from id to the list of `Data` objects with that id. E.g. `lstN[1]` is the list of all objects with ID = 1

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just define

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
     QList<Data> lst;
}
```

which would define 3 lists, each called `lst`. The problem is, the lifetime of each is restricted to the loop body. That's likely not what you want.

I suspect you want a *list of lists*. The `QList< >` template is generic, it can contain any other type including another `QList< >`. So you'd get `QList<QList< Data > >`

Comment: lifetime should not be restricted. I want to use these lists further to fill data. How can I declare with a list of list? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This would create 4 lists